# NelmioApiDoc v3 / Swagger - multiple API docs

Tags: symfony, swagger, symfony-3.3, nelmioapidocbundle

NelmioApiDoc v2 allowed to use multiple `views` parameter so I can hide some endpoints and present them on different URL

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/multiple-api-doc.html

Is it possible to do it in NelmioApiDoc v3 which is using Swagger?

I am using Symfony 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to be called "Areas" now in NelmioApiDoc v3.
Thanks to this feature, you can define areas which will each generates a different documentation :

You just have to define those areas in your config.yml:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [ ^/api ]
        custom:
            path_patterns: [ ^/custom ]
        another_custom:
            path_patterns: [ ^/anothercustom ]
```

Then you need to update your routing.yml file:

```
app.swagger_ui:
    path: /api/doc/{area}
    methods: GET
    defaults: { _controller: nelmio_api_doc.controller.swagger_ui, area: default }
```

You can read about it on [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/areas.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18691857)

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya: understood! I edited my answer ;)

Comment: I think I can accept your answer now. V3.1 is now published